# Regular Expression for Census Tracts

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am working on making sure a form input is parsed correctly through google forms and I was trying to use my limited regex knowledge to make sure that people do not input tracts incorrectly.

usually a tract is given in an example such as 5129.01
All tracts in the county start with 5, have a second character that is either a 0 or a 1,and if it is a 1, the third character is either [0 - 3] else its [0-9].

I have a working expression but I would like to ensure that if the second character is a 1 the user wouldn't be able to enter a tract like 5150.01

This is what I have:
`^5[0-1]([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]{2}))?$`
and this is what is not working:
 `^5[0-1](?(?<=1)\d|[0-3])(\.([0-9]{2}))?$`

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: You only mention rules for the first three characters but don't mention anything about the 4th or the characters after the decimal place. Can you elaborate?

Comment: the 4th character is a digit [0-9] and afterwards there is an optional 3 more characters which are a decimal followed by two digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your question, please comment and I can edit accordingly.

The pattern:

```
^(?:51[0-3]|50[0-9])[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

A visual representation:

[image]

HTML implementation:

```html
<input name="example" pattern="^(?:51[0-3]|50[0-9])[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$">
```

Value validation examples:

```
+----------+--------+
|  Value   | Status |
+----------+--------+
|       51 | fail   |
|      510 | fail   |
|     5101 | pass   |
|     5111 | pass   |
|     5121 | pass   |
|     5131 | pass   |
|     5141 | fail   |
|    5102. | fail   |
|   5102.1 | pass   |
|  5102.12 | pass   |
| 5102.123 | fail   |
|       50 | fail   |
|      500 | fail   |
|     5001 | pass   |
|     5011 | pass   |
|     5021 | pass   |
|     5031 | pass   |
|     5041 | pass   |
|     5051 | pass   |
|     5061 | pass   |
|     5071 | pass   |
|     5081 | pass   |
|     5091 | pass   |
|    50911 | fail   |
|    5092. | fail   |
|   5092.1 | pass   |
|  5092.12 | pass   |
| 5092.123 | fail   |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't think to separate into 51 and 50 that makes so much sense as opposed to doing a look ahead or look behind. Thanks again!

Comment: @BenjaminMiller Great to hear I've answered your question! Please mark as accepted.